# How to configure or disable Content Security Policy(CSP) in Nuxt 3 to render images?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm tryin to render some images from a specific URL in Nuxt, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

I know this is a CSP error, and i tried fixing it by configuring my CSP headers in Nuxt, but nothing seems to work. Heres my Nuxt config :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  security: {
    headers: {
      xXSSProtection: '1',
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        'img-src': ["'self'", 's.gravatar.com', 'data:']
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But this is not working, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and fix using this module
https://github.com/Baroshem/nuxt-security

The documentation to solve your problem:
https://github.com/Baroshem/nuxt-security/blob/main/docs/content/1.getting-started/2.configuration.md

Comment: but the 'img-src' property is not working. thats the problem.  Im getting the error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
(property) 'img-src'?: string[] | undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you set `img-src` to `false`, you are allowing everything. You can also be specific and set it to `["'self'", 'data:', 'https://www.example.com']`. Setting `img-src` to `undefined` (also a valid value) seems to give you the default settings, which are `["'self'", 'data:']`.

Your `nuxt.config.ts` file could look like this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    'nuxt-security',
  ],
  security: {
    headers: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'https://www.example.com'],
      },
    },
  },
})
```

A couple of gotchas:

- This value works: `'https://www.example.com'` and this does not: `'example.com'`
- This value works:  `"'self'"` and this does not:  `'self'`